# Halt the server daily at a specific hour

Tags: centos, cron

I have a CentOS 5 server, I want it to halt DAILY at 21:00 and wake up DAILY at 8:00

For the wake up I did it in the bios, but for the halt I want to configure it through cron. How to do it with SSH?

I'm logged as ROOT, and now I want to pass a command that tells the server to halt EVERYDAY at 21:00.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSH is just a way of logging in. If you are logged in as you say, you don't need SSH anymore.

A command to shutdown is `shutdown -h now`.

You edit your current user's crontab with `crontab -e`.

In a user's crontab, the line to execute he above statement should be

```
0 21 * * * /sbin/shutdown -h now
```

Comment: No, SSH is just the way I login to the server. It has nothing to deal with what I'm looking for, I just want the full command to type to get the server to halt everyday at 21:00

Comment: But why did you then write "How to do it with SSH?"?

Comment: I mean how to do it from the command line while logged as ROOT in SSH (putty)